# Explanation of DNNClassifier in TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, deep-learning, tensorflow

I used tf.estimator.DNNClassifier, a high-level API in tensorflow, to perform a binary classification.
It works very well for my purpose, but I am a principiante in Machine Learning and I would like to know better how it works.

[Considering this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier), what kind of neaural network is used? How is it structured? What activation do you use? And so on.

I apologize for the trivial question, but I'm a beginner and I would want a simple general guide.

Comment: Take a look at the source code here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py

It looks like it's just a standard neural network with a variable number of hidden layers, and a logistic output.

Answer (score 1):

General tip: if you set `model_dir` parameter of your estimator, it will log model summary into that directory while training and you can then run [tensorboard tool](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) to visualize your particular graph.

Regarding [`tf.estimator.DNNClassifier`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier), its graph is a just collection of `dense` layers. The example from the documentation:

```
estimator = DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=[categorical_feature_a_emb, categorical_feature_b_emb],
    hidden_units=[1024, 512, 256])
```

... defines 3 hidden dense layers with `1024` units, `512` units and `256` units. In addition to that, there is an input layer, which size is determined by `feature_columns` parameter, and the head (can be binary or multiclass depending on `n_classes` parameter). Hidden layers can also be followed by the dropout layer, if you specify `dropout`. And that's it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your explanation. Just one thing, why is this DNNClassifier working on images? Actually this model performs really good on MNIST data. However, I don't get it why a model like this and not CNN is working pretty well on image data. Would you explain it please?

Comment: CNN will definitely hit higher accuracy on images. But for MNIST there is probably a strong correlation between the number of black pixels and the label. This allows a pretty simple NN to show fairly good accuracy, but not as good as modern CNNs do.